# Breeze - Can't Create Entity when PK is an autogenerated ID

Tags: oracle, knockout.js, entity-framework-6, single-page-application, breeze

I have used breeze's CreateEntity a few times when table's PK is a user-entered value.  And a few times with SQL SERVER when PK is an IDENTITY.  This is my first time trying to do it when PK is autogenerated ID (actually a "sequence") in ORACLE. It isn't working.

I do check first to make sure I have fetched the Metadata then create the new, empty entity that will be filled in with values by user.

My code to createEntity (newEntity is a knockout Observable):

```
function createEntity(newEntity) {
    newEntity(manager.createEntity(entityNames.escctransactions, {}));   <<<<< this fails
    return;
}
```

The Error:
Cannot attach an object of type  (ESCC_TRANSACTIONS:... ) to an EntityManager without first setting its key or setting its entityType 'AutoGeneratedKeyType' property to something other than 'None'

I know I need to set the AutoGeneratedKeyType to "Identity" but not sure how to do it.  Tried this when I'm inititalizing the metadata, but still getting same error so it's obviously not working:

```
   var entyType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("ESCC_TRANSACTIONS");
   entyType.setProperties({ AutoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity });
```

I've seen something about doing it in a constructor but I've never used a constructor in JavaScript. Also something about changing it in a config?

Using Breeze 1.6, Knockout.js 3.4, .NET 4.5.2 framework

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself and it's working now.  The code to set AutoGeneratedKeyType is as follows:

```
var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("ESCC_TRANSACTIONS");
entityType.autoGeneratedKeyType = "Identity";
```

Or this works:

```
var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("ESCC_TRANSACTIONS");
entityType.autoGeneratedKeyType = breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity;
```

And in spite of the Breeze documentation for AutoGeneratedKeyType here: 
http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/AutoGeneratedKeyType.html, it's not a capital "A" in Auto, it's a small "a".